# Bypassing DC applied group policy Objects

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have local admin access(password) of windows 7 machine on domain environment. Could someone help how to bypass or remove domain controller applied policy?

Also I would like to know how do I determine/find registry locations where DC applied group policy objects are configured and how to tweak or disable them?

Is there any automated way or tool to achieve this?

Comment: "Could someone help how to bypass or remove domain controller applied policy?" - You would need to be an Administrator on the active directory itself in to do this.  Are you one?  "Is there any automated way or tool to achieve this?" - It's called `gpedit.msc` and it's built into Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound and gpedit.msc won't even let you modify or disable a lot of group policy settings, if they're domain applied.

Comment: But still there should be alternative way or workaround. How about registry editor?

Comment: @BenFranchuk - If they were an admin they could change the GP that is applied to a specific machine and/or user group though.

Comment: @G-ONE - You didn't update your question to indicate if you are an Administrator on the domain itself.   What you want can't be done with local Administrator permissions.  If you are not an Administrator this question will be closed, because questions seeking ways to get around Administrator controls, is out of scope for Superuser (and Serverfault) which are the only two places this question would be on topic.

Comment: @ramhound if they were a DOMAIN admin, sure, but local admin as he is or system specific admin? Correct me if I'm wrong but those changes are impossible unless you're a domain admin.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am neither domain Administrator nor member of domain administrator group.

Comment: @G-ONE you will be unable to bypass the GP in that case, ask for an exception for your machine, your administrator has that fine of control over the policies

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, if you tweak the registry as to avoid Group Policy, its somewhat likely that the Group Policy will be reapplied. You can test this by performing your registry edit and then in powershell entering `gpupdate /force`, which will tell the system to pull its Group Policy updates earlier than the scheduled or typical interval that it would. This is assuming, mind you, you can find which registries the settings applied by policy that you would like to change are- As far as I know, there's no tool to do this, you've just gotta know how to navigate the registry, which is, at the least, risky. Anyways, Gpupdate doesn't force anything the computer wouldn't do; to say, your computer would update its group policies either way, anyway, thus why a Registry Edit likely isn't your best option, and for that matter, neither really is anything on a user/client system side. This leads me to my next point...

Your best solution would be to remove yourself from the group affected by the GPOs that are affecting you/you want to avoid on a Domain Controller, as otherwise unless you take your system off of the domain, it's almost guaranteed that the setting changes you make will be changed back. Also, if you're not authorized to be making these changes, it's possible that your system administrator will notice you're trying to avoid their applied policies, and that could potentially land you in some hot water. I don't know what you're attempting to do here, but it sounds somewhat risky.

So in summary, you've gotta configure this on the Domain Controller side, for if you manage to pull something off locally, it'll likely get reset or not work at all.

Comment: Is it possible to create Local Group policy object that will override domain GPO and bypass this?

Comment: Depends on the configuration of the Domain applied policy; if it's set to enforce on systems then that means the configuration in the policy will always be this way on the client system, and overwrite any changes you make, or worse, could mess up the configuration entirely on your system.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you attempting here and what kind of environment are you in? Does your assumed Systems Administrator have a monitoring software? Agents installed on the systems?

Comment: I want to add few websites in Internet Explorer Trusted sites zone. Any alternative way that override Domail GPO.

Any One???

Comment: I'll say again, it's probably not going to happen; I'm a sysadmin, and I set domain GPOs so that my user's systems are all uniform, so that there aren't any vulnerabilities, and so that my users can't modify settings that will nullify the first two above points. If there were a way to dodge GPOs, everyone would do it, and administrators like myself would need to find an alternate way of locking down systems. For your situation, you MAY be able to get away with changing your internet settings in IE, to allow the illicit sites you wanna use, however, these settings are probably locked down too.